# Query to json firebase object or redux state

Tags: firebase, dictionary, redux, foreach

I'm building my first web app with React, Redux and Firebase, it's about registering the assistance of students (alumnos) to lessons (clases). I've the following database structure (the same in Redux state, this.props).

```
  "clases" : {
    "-LpQkLyGXEd-Up8hExTx" : {
      "alumnos" : [ "-LpKkSh0E5jiuM0JCCpS", "-LpQi33M-0OSS4Jvup8k" ],
      "fechaClase" : "20-09-2019",
      "profesor" : "Nacho",
      "tema" : "Misión"
    },
    "-LpQmExVsWtW1uPHLK52" : {
      "alumnos" : [ "-LpJvbXb2FjgZvvBv3ei", "-LpKkSh0E5jiuM0JCCpS", "-LpQi33M-0OSS4Jvup8k", "-LpQiDGlRWITax2t6U2A" ],
      "fechaClase" : "22-09-2019",
      "profesor" : "Nacho",
      "tema" : "Bautismo"
    },
    "-LpQqZ_uWu8HxROagVjN" : {
      "alumnos" : [ "-LpKkSh0E5jiuM0JCCpS", "-LpQi33M-0OSS4Jvup8k", "-LpQiPCS2cIK7opMNqyH" ],
      "fechaClase" : "21-09-2019",
      "profesor" : "Manzo, Ignacio",
      "tema" : "Bautismo"
    }
```

I want to select a student (alumno), and know which lessons have made. Do I have to make a double map to the object? Can you give some help?

This is the deployed app https://metanoia-ic.herokuapp.com/
This is my github repository: https://github.com/tonicanada/metanoia

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Object.keys` to be able to use `filter` and `include` `Array.prototype` methods. Asuming that `clases` is the object containing all the state, I would do something like this:

```
const studentId = this.props.studentId; // or any other value

const clasesPerStudent = Object.keys(clases).filter(clase =>
  clases[clase].alumnos.includes(studentId)
);
```